# Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:44326

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, localhost

I'm facing this error when I've to fetch data from web API from localhost, android app is running in emulator.

> Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:44326

No response is getting from the localhost server in xamarin app whereas I'm able to fetch result in postman and in browser as well. I put URL ("https://localhost:44326/api/passportStatus") in xamarin MainPage.xaml.cs. are these info sufficient to know what I want actually?

This is my mainpage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {`public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            empDetails();
        }

        private async void empDetails()
        {
            var result = "";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var API_URL = "https://localhost:44326/api/passportStatus";
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(API_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage respons = await client.GetAsync(API_URL);
        result = await respons.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var PassportDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<detail>>(result);
        EmpDeatils.ItemsSource = PassportDetails;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would normally set a base address against the client, and then pass in the endpoint url. Are you not passing any headers, either?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-web-api-using-httpclient/ take a read of this tutorial

Comment: Well here's your problem... "android app is running in emulator." The emulator has its own 127.0.0.1 address that won't get routed out to the host computer. If your host computer had an IPv4 address of 192.168.0.47 then configure your Web API service to be listening on `http://192.168.0.47:44326/`, or even `http://0.0.0.0:44326/`, then have your Xamarin app configured to request from `http://192.168.0.47:44326/`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried it but not working. now the error is System.Net.WebException: 'Failed to connect to /192.16.28.178:45457'

Answer (score 2):

check whether you have installed nuget package conveyor,if it is ok edit API URL as follows http://192.168.8.200:45455/ in yours question add 44326 insted of 45455

Comment: thats works fine for me.please try to express your idea clearly

Answer (score 1):

Update your code like below

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            empDetails();
        }

        private async void empDetails()
        {
            var result = "";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var API_URL = "https://192.168.0.47:44326/api/";//Updated
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(API_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage respons = await client.GetAsync("passportStatus");//Updated
        result = await respons.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var PassportDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<detail>>(result);
        EmpDeatils.ItemsSource = PassportDetails;
        }
    }
```

Hope this will resolve ur issue

Answer (score 1):

**127.0.0.1** is localhost; it's the IP address of every local machine,
that means you try to create a request from an Android App to an Android device

In another word, you try to connect with an Android device, not with a computer Localhost.

for that, you need to change the localhost in the computer from **127.0.0.1**  to the current **IP4** of your computer.

now try this extension and follow the instructions to do that in Visual studio:
**https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti**

Answer (score 1):

On Visual Studio 2022 17.7+ version there is an option to create 'dev tunnels' which do exactly what conveyor/ngrok does.